# Unable to run code on Aldebaran Nao

Tags: python, nao-robot

I have made a simple program using Python SDK in file *say.py* . Aldebaran Nao is connected to network at IP 172.26.96.164

```
from naoqi import ALProxy
pr = ALProxy("ALTextToSpeech", "172.26.96.164", 9559)
pr.say("Hello, You are awesome !")
```

The code runs fine. But when I start local version of Naoqi on computer

```
> & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Aldebaran\Choregraphe 1.12.5.3\bin\naoqi-bin.exe'
```

The code for *say.py* stops running with following error.

```
PS C:\Users\admin\Desktop\nehchal> python say.py
[INFO ] Starting ALNetwork
[ERROR] Connection failed ! Port 54010 is already in use. Are you already running NaoQi? Use --broker-port option to specify a different port.
[INFO ] Stopping ALNetwork
[INFO ] Exit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "say.py", line 2, in <module>
pr = ALProxy("ALTextToSpeech", "172.26.96.164", 9559)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\naoqi.py", line 230, in __init__
inaoqi.proxy.__init__(self, args[0], args[1], args[2])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\inaoqi.py", line 322, in __init__
this = _inaoqi.new_proxy(*args)
RuntimeError:   ALBroker::runBroker
    Port 54010 is not free. Another broker is using this port.
```

Can someone please explain what does this error exactly mean? How to know who is using this port? How do I free the port or how can I use alternate port?

Comment: Update:
I think there is some race condition for acquiring the port. I have solved the problem by using <try, except> in while loop where it tries again if it fails. Now, generally it connects by attempting for maximum 4-5 times.

Answer (score 1):

look at the naoqi command line option:

- -p [ --broker-port ] arg (=9559)  Port of the server, default is 9559
- --pport arg (=0)                  Port of the parent broker, default is no
                                  parent (0).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to see if/and what is using the port using the netstad command from a prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Try to download an [older version of sdk](
https://community.aldebaran.com/en/resources/software/212-3-python-naoqi-sdk).